# In PS, how does one make two or more layers on the same level?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I've got two elements that both have drop shadows, and they are very close together (say 30px).

Is there a way to make sure that each layer's drop doesn't affect the other layer?

Answer (score 4):

Group the layers. Add the drop shadow to the group.

Comment: What if I don't want both the layers to have the same kind of drop shadow? Eg. different size or spread?